# export to pdf using codeigniter & bootstrap

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a web project. In my project, i would like to give button to export file to pdf. i'm using bootstrap & codeigniter.

can anyone give example for export file to pdf in codeigniter ?

Comment: I assume you have seen [this](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf)?

Answer (score 1):

Found this while trying to do the same. https://davidsimpson.me/2013/05/19/using-mpdf-with-codeigniter/

In place of `redirect()` function used on the page, you can use the code below to force download. Note that `redirect()` will only open the file in some browsers like chrome.

```
$this->load->helper('download');

$data = file_get_contents(base_url("downloads/reports/$filename.pdf")); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'mynewfile.pdf';

force_download($name, $data);
```

Don't forget to add the **.pdf** extension to **$name**

Answer (score 0):

I am using TCPDF to generate pdf files in codeigniter. check this out.[TCPDF examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)